# Autopilot could not be installed on VMware ESXi 5.5

Tags: vmware, openstack, landscape, openstack-autopilot

Hi Ubuntu OpenStack Autopilot team,

I could not install the autopilot on VMware ESXi 5.5 though nested virtualization was enabled. I was running Ubuntu 14.04.1 with latest update.

This one when I was trying to install with single system mode:

```
INFO • 11-12 09:53:36 [LINE:102, FUNC:<module>] • cloudinstall • cloud-install starting
INFO • 11-12 09:53:36 [LINE:73, FUNC:status_context] • cloudinstall.core • Get started by entering an Openstack password to use in your cloud ..
DEBUG • 11-12 09:53:36 [LINE:101, FUNC:_build_widget] • cloudinstall.ui.dialog • Num items: 2, items: <BoxAdapter selectable flow widget <ListBox selectable box widget> height=2>
DEBUG • 11-12 09:53:40 [LINE:108, FUNC:submit] • cloudinstall.ui.dialog • Callback on : OrderedDict([('password', <EditInput selectable flow widget>), ('confirm_password', <EditInput selectable flow widget>)])
INFO • 11-12 09:53:40 [LINE:73, FUNC:status_context] • cloudinstall.core • Choose your installation path ..
DEBUG • 11-12 09:53:40 [LINE:101, FUNC:_build_widget] • cloudinstall.ui.dialog • Num items: 4, items: <BoxAdapter selectable flow widget <ListBox selectable box widget> height=4>
DEBUG • 11-12 09:53:43 [LINE:157, FUNC:submit] • cloudinstall.ui • Callback on : OrderedDict([('Single', <RadioButton selectable flow widget 'Single' state=True>), ('Multi', <RadioButton selectable flow widget 'Multi' state=False>), ('Multi with existing MAAS', <RadioButton selectable flow widget 'Multi with existing MAAS' state=False>), ('Landscape', <RadioButton selectable flow widget 'Landscape' state=False>)])
INFO • 11-12 09:53:43 [LINE:73, FUNC:status_context] • cloudinstall.core • Building environment
DEBUG • 11-12 10:00:36 [LINE:417, FUNC:container_run] • cloudinstall.utils • Running in container: sudo -H -u ubuntu TERM=xterm256-color ssh -t -q -l ubuntu -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" -o "UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" -i /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa 10.0.3.169 mkdir -p .juju
DEBUG • 11-12 10:00:38 [LINE:421, FUNC:container_run] • cloudinstall.utils • b''
DEBUG • 11-12 10:00:39 [LINE:417, FUNC:container_run] • cloudinstall.utils • Running in container: sudo -H -u ubuntu TERM=xterm256-color ssh -t -q -l ubuntu -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" -o "UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" -i /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa 10.0.3.169 mkdir -p ~/.cloud-install
DEBUG • 11-12 10:00:40 [LINE:50, FUNC:global_exchandler] • cloudinstall.utils • Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/utils.py", line 420, in container_run
    ret = check_output(cmd, stderr=STDOUT, shell=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 616, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'sudo -H -u ubuntu TERM=xterm256-color ssh -t -q -l ubuntu -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" -o "UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" -i /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa 10.0.3.169 mkdir -p ~/.cloud-install' returned non-zero exit status 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/utils.py", line 64, in run
    super().run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 868, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/single_install.py", line 159, in do_install
    self.copy_installdata_and_set_perms()
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/single_install.py", line 105, in copy_installdata_and_set_perms
    utils.container_run(self.container_name, 'mkdir -p ~/.cloud-install')
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/utils.py", line 424, in container_run
    "({1}:{2}) Error: {3}".format(cmd, name, ip, e))
Exception: There was a problem running (sudo -H -u ubuntu TERM=xterm256-color ssh -t -q -l ubuntu -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" -o "UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" -i /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa 10.0.3.169 mkdir -p ~/.cloud-install) in the container (uoi-bootstrap:10.0.3.169) Error: Command 'sudo -H -u ubuntu TERM=xterm256-color ssh -t -q -l ubuntu -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" -o "UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" -i /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa 10.0.3.169 mkdir -p ~/.cloud-install' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

And this one was when I tried to install with Landscape mode:

```
INFO • 11-17 02:36:00 [LINE:102, FUNC:<module>] • cloudinstall • cloud-install starting
INFO • 11-17 02:36:00 [LINE:73, FUNC:status_context] • cloudinstall.core • Get started by entering an Openstack password to use in your cloud ..
DEBUG • 11-17 02:36:00 [LINE:101, FUNC:_build_widget] • cloudinstall.ui.dialog • Num items: 2, items: <BoxAdapter selectable flow widget <ListBox selectable box widget> height=2>
DEBUG • 11-17 02:36:05 [LINE:108, FUNC:submit] • cloudinstall.ui.dialog • Callback on : OrderedDict([('password', <EditInput selectable flow widget>), ('confirm_password', <EditInput selectable flow widget>)])
INFO • 11-17 02:36:05 [LINE:73, FUNC:status_context] • cloudinstall.core • Choose your installation path ..
DEBUG • 11-17 02:36:05 [LINE:101, FUNC:_build_widget] • cloudinstall.ui.dialog • Num items: 4, items: <BoxAdapter selectable flow widget <ListBox selectable box widget> height=4>
DEBUG • 11-17 02:36:07 [LINE:157, FUNC:submit] • cloudinstall.ui • Callback on : OrderedDict([('Single', <RadioButton selectable flow widget 'Single' state=False>), ('Multi', <RadioButton selectable flow widget 'Multi' state=False>), ('Multi with existing MAAS', <RadioButton selectable flow widget 'Multi with existing MAAS' state=False>), ('Landscape', <RadioButton selectable flow widget 'Landscape' state=True>)])
INFO • 11-17 02:36:07 [LINE:73, FUNC:status_context] • cloudinstall.core • Please enter your Landscape information and optionally an existing MAAS Server IP. If MAAS is not defined a new one will be created for you.
DEBUG • 11-17 02:36:07 [LINE:101, FUNC:_build_widget] • cloudinstall.ui.dialog • Num items: 5, items: <BoxAdapter selectable flow widget <ListBox selectable box widget> height=5>
DEBUG • 11-17 02:36:22 [LINE:108, FUNC:submit] • cloudinstall.ui.dialog • Callback on : OrderedDict([('admin_email', <EditInput selectable flow widget>), ('admin_name', <EditInput selectable flow widget>), ('system_email', <EditInput selectable flow widget>), ('maas_server', <EditInput selectable flow widget>), ('maas_apikey', <EditInput selectable flow widget>)])
INFO • 11-17 02:36:22 [LINE:73, FUNC:status_context] • cloudinstall.core • Running ..
DEBUG • 11-17 02:36:22 [LINE:70, FUNC:_save_lds_creds] • cloudinstall.landscape_install • No maas credentials entered, doing a new MAAS install
INFO • 11-17 02:36:22 [LINE:73, FUNC:status_context] • cloudinstall.core • Please select a network interface that is not currently listening to any DHCP or DNS requests. This will be the interface MAAS will use to manage its own DNS/DHCP services.
DEBUG • 11-17 02:36:22 [LINE:50, FUNC:global_exchandler] • cloudinstall.utils • Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/openstack-install", line 104, in <module>
    install.start()
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/core.py", line 263, in start
    self.main_loop()
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/install.py", line 72, in main_loop
    self.loop.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 274, in run
    self.screen.run_wrapper(self._run)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/raw_display.py", line 268, in run_wrapper
    return fn()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 339, in _run
    self.event_loop.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 669, in run
    self._loop()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 706, in _loop
    self._watch_files[fd]()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 390, in _update
    self.process_input(keys)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 490, in process_input
    k = self._topmost_widget.keypress(self.screen_size, k)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/container.py", line 588, in keypress
    *self.calculate_padding_filler(size, True)), key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/decoration.py", line 836, in keypress
    return self._original_widget.keypress((maxcol,), key)
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/ui/dialog.py", line 53, in keypress
    super().keypress(size, key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/container.py", line 1583, in keypress
    key = self.focus.keypress(tsize, key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/container.py", line 2265, in keypress
    key = w.keypress((mc,) + size[1:], key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/decoration.py", line 385, in keypress
    return self._original_widget.keypress((maxcol, self.height), key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/listbox.py", line 985, in keypress
    key = focus_widget.keypress((maxcol,),key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/container.py", line 2265, in keypress
    key = w.keypress((mc,) + size[1:], key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/wimp.py", line 535, in keypress
    self._emit('click')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/widget.py", line 463, in _emit
    signals.emit_signal(self, name, self, *args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/signals.py", line 264, in emit
    result |= self._call_callback(callback, user_arg, user_args, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/signals.py", line 294, in _call_callback
    return bool(callback(*args_to_pass))
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/ui/dialog.py", line 109, in submit
    self.emit_done_signal(self.input_items)
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/ui/dialog.py", line 115, in emit_done_signal
    emit_signal(self, 'done', *args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/signals.py", line 264, in emit
    result |= self._call_callback(callback, user_arg, user_args, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/signals.py", line 294, in _call_callback
    return bool(callback(*args_to_pass))
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/landscape_install.py", line 71, in _save_lds_creds
    self._do_install_new_maas()
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/landscape_install.py", line 55, in _do_install_new_maas
    post_tasks=self.landscape_tasks).run()
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/multi_install.py", line 246, in run
    self.prompt_for_interface()
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/multi_install.py", line 255, in prompt_for_interface
    if_names = sorted(get_network_interfaces().keys())
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/netutils.py", line 75, in get_network_interfaces
    rd[name] = dict(ipaddress=get_ip_addr(name),
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/netutils.py", line 35, in get_ip_addr
    return str(_networkinfo(interface)['network'].ip)
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/netutils.py", line 27, in _networkinfo
    nw = re.search("inet (\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+/\d+)", out).groups()[0]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
```

There are more error logs different kind than those above but I didn't keep it. Will send more later if found any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like you have hit two separate bugs that were both fixed last week.

If you update the packages and try again, you should have more success:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openstack
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Mike, I have updated it to the latest with no luck either. How to clean uninstall? Using the sudo openstack-install -u didn't work well. Should I purge the postgresql juju and maas packages too as well when uninstalling and start with clean slate? :)

Comment: @chrone yea since you're doing a landscape install it's a little more effort in uninstalling since it does affect several technologies. Essentially doing a apt-get purge of maas, destroying your juju environment, and moving ~/.cloud-install out of the way you can do a fresh install

Comment: @Mike thanks again! :) I was able to set squid on other machine to cache the deb packages, but unfortunately it didn't cache the "Importing MAAS boot images". I have set the environment to use http_proxy but to no luck at all. Any tips? :P

Comment: @chrone You can set the `MAAS_HTTP_PROXY` before running openstack-install as described here: http://ubuntu-cloud-installer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/developer.setup.html#running-the-openstack-installer

Comment: @gangstaluv thanks for the tip. i did a quick read on it, so i should build the openstack-installer by myself to get it working on proxy, right? :)

Comment: @chrone not sure i follow what you mean, once the MAAS_HTTP_PROXY has the boot images cached it'll just pull from there during the "Importing MAAS boot images" stage

Comment: hi @gangstaluv, what i'm saying is when we issue openstack-install, it downloads maas, juju, and its own bootstrap image or so. i want them to be cached in squid proxy. i know once the maas has run properly, all its client nodes will use maas proxy for faster deploying, tested by installing maas and its node manually. :)

Comment: @chrone i dont think you have to rebuild openstack-install, just setup youre own squid proxy to cache what you need

Comment: @gangstaluv, unfortunately it doesn't obey the system-wide proxy i've set. :( newest openstack-install package does tell us to do the maas installation first manually so that we can set the proxy settings in MAAS, but not when it downloads the Juju LXC instances. I've set the /etc/environment, /etc/apt/apt.conf, and /etc/wgetrc to no luck caching the Juju LXC instances/bootstraps download.

Comment: @Mike McCracken, I'm able to run the single mode installer inside VMware ESXi at the moment. Thanks all! :)